# Login into multiple framed or unframed outside pages using single login entry splash page

Tags: iframe, proxy, autologin

Have a page that has 3 vendor related login pages iframed in.  Clients often times are given the same login information for all three of these outside pages, but have to login three times to use them.  Is there an easy way or best practice to set up a login splash form that feeds the login information into these frames, or into new loaded portals to the vendor pages so they don't have to do the end user doesn't have to do the work three times.

Main page is
http://www.fhkaysing.com/
These are presently being iframed in: under menu titles

> WebLink Login
>   Carrier Upload
>   E-Tracker

`http://www2.fhkaysing.com/WebLink8/ & http://www2.fhkaysing.com:9300/fhkfiletracker/UploadLogin.aspx & http://www2.fhkaysing.com:9300/fhkfiletracker/FHKEtrackLogin.aspx`